# How to locally manage git lfs files (in same directory with normal git files, if possible)

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-lfs

I'm trying to work with git lfs (Large File Support) files on my Windows 10 computer.  The ultimate goal is to be able to do a diff between the files in the git repository and the files in another folder, but this question is about the way git lfs files are stored and managed locally.  I'm using SourceTree as well as command line git and have Cygwin installed (and I'm very familiar with Unix commands and development in general).

In my local repository (a clone of a BitBucket repository), some of them seem to be showing up with full content under the directory structure where the rest of the git files are stored.  Others are showing up as zero byte files, which I understand it some kind of pointer used by git lfs.  I also know that the `.git/lfs/objects/` folder seems to be where the local copies of some of the LFS objects are stored.

When I do `git lfs ls-files`, some of the files that I know are checked in to git lfs aren't listed at all (some large .mp4 video files, specifically).  I am on the latest version of the correct branch (master) where the files are checked in and visible and downloadable via the web interface.  I have tried doing `git lfs pull` and many other commands, but the files aren't showing up the way I need and expect them to.

Ideally, I would like to have a copy of the current version of the lfs files (content and all) in the same folder structure (locally) with the rest of the files.  I am fine if it is elsewhere (locally) so long as I have some way to get at it.  (I can figure out how to deal with it if I need to, so long as I have the content of the files available.)

So what am I missing or doing wrong?  Why can't I locate the content of some files?  Why does `git lfs ls-files` not list all the files I'm expecting it to?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the main issue was with a merge that wasn't done correctly.  Some of the files were either deleted or lfs was not enabled on the host doing the merge or something like that.  Re-adding the files fixed the issue.